# How to put a lot of siblings into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have six divs like this:

```
<div style="display:none">div1</div>
<div style="display:none">div2</div>
<div style="display:none">div3</div>
<div style="display:none">div4</div>
<div style="display:none">div5</div>
<div style="display:none">div6</div>
```

I want to put the first 4 divs into a hidden div,  and the 2 next div into another hidden div, resulting in a DOM like this:

```
<div class="glob" style="display:none">
    <div style="display:none">div1</div>
    <div style="display:none">div2</div>
    <div style="display:none">div3</div>
    <div style="display:none">div4</div>
</div>

<div class="glob" style="display:none">
    <div style="display:none">div5</div>
    <div style="display:none">div6</div>
</div>
```

And after doing this, i want to add a combo with 2 values, when you click on the first choice it shows the first "global" div, and when you click on the second choice it shows the second "global" div. I have no idea how to do the first thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want help with exactly? As well as what the 'first choice' means in your last paragraph?

Comment: Olivier, take a look at my answer, I updated it with your second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.

The key is to use `.slice()`

```js
var divs = $("div");
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 4) {
  divs.slice(i, i + 4).css("display", "block").wrapAll("<div class=\"glob\" style=\"display:none\">");
  $('select[name="show"]').append("<option value=\"" + count + "\">glob " + (count + 1) + "</option>")
  count++;
}
$('select[name="show"]').change(function() {
  $('.glob').hide().eq($(this).find("option:selected").val()).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none">div1</div>
<div style="display:none">div2</div>
<div style="display:none">div3</div>
<div style="display:none">div4</div>
<div style="display:none">div5</div>
<div style="display:none">div6</div>

<select name="show">
<option>select what glob you want to see</option
</select>
```

Comment: He told combobox.

Comment: I asked for a combo but this is perfect. The key was about `wrapAll` because  I didn't know it. Thank you very much for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably don't need to hide all siblings div but just the parent div.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('select').on('change', function() {
        $("#parent1").hide();
        $("#parent2").hide();     
        $('#sel').val() == 1 ?  $("#parent1").show() : $("#parent2").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="sel">
  <option value ="0">-----SELECT------</option>
  <option value ="1">Show Parent 1</option>
  <option value ="2">Show Parent 2</option>
</select>

<div id="parent1" class="glob" style="display:none">
    <div>div1</div>
    <div>div2</div>
    <div>div3</div>
    <div>div4</div>
</div>

<div id="parent2" class="glob" style="display:none">
    <div>div5</div>
    <div>div6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want them to be hidden in the first place = when the page shows up, so the user dont see them "flashing + disappear".

Comment: Above snippet hides anything in the parent div, it won't flash and disappear on page load.

Comment: I use Django framework which will display a list of div siblings, I have no choice. Dont ask me to change the base HTML where I have 6 hidden divs, because I cant...

Comment: You should have mentioned Django framework tag in the question.

Comment: This is not about Django at all, it's only about having a fixed, non modifiable, set of hidden divs....